# SOQL all files in folder

Tags: soql, files

Using Files, is that possible? I've tried:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM ContentVersions) FROM ContentFolder

SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM ContentDocuments) FROM ContentFolder

SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM ContentDocumentLinks) FROM ContentFolder
```

and these queries do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Id, Title, FileExtension FROM ContentFolderItem WHERE ParentContentFolderId IN (SELECT Id FROM ContentFolder WHERE Name = 'Folder Name')
```